# OpenCV Cascade Performance: valid XML error

Tags: xml, opencv, haar-classifier

I am running `opencv 2.4.8` inside a `conda` environment. I am able to train a [car detector](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fpiFrShc7g) using

`opencv_traincascade -data data -vec cars.vec -bg bg.txt -numPos 500 -numNeg 500 -numStages 2 -w 48 -h 24`

However, I can not check the performance using

`opencv_performance -data data -info cars.txt`

I receive a parsing error:

```
OpenCV Error: Parsing error (data(0): 
Valid XML should start with '<?xml ...?>') in icvXMLParse, 
file /Users/jhelmus/anaconda/conda-bld/work/opencv-2.4.8/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp, line 2252
libc++abi.dylib:terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::
Exception: /Users/jhelmus/anaconda/conda-bld/work/opencv-2.4.8/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp:2252: 
error: (-212) data(0): Valid XML should start with '<?xml ...?>' in function icvXMLParse
```

I have checked the .xml files and they are appropriately formatted with

`<?xml version="1.0"?>`

as the first line.

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a poorly worded error message; the issue is with the format of the saved detector.  `opencv_performance` uses an old format that is output by `opencv_haartraining`, and doesn't work on detectors saved in the format used by `opencv_traincascade` ([docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html)).

There are two solutions:

1) You could train your detector using `opencv_haartraining` ([man page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/debian/1/opencv_haartraining/)).  This is not recommended, since `opencv_haartraining` is limited to a single thread.  It is also a deprecated method.

2) You can add the `-baseFormatSave` flag to your `opencv_traincascade` command ([man page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/debian/1/opencv_traincascade/)), forcing it to save the detector in the old format, i.e.:

```
opencv_traincascade -data data -vec cars.vec -bg bg.txt -numPos 500 -numNeg 500 -numStages 2 -w 48 -h 24 -baseFormatSave
```

This feature has a bug, however, that leaves out a classifier type declaration.  You can fix it by running

```
sed -i 's/<cascade>/<cascade type_id="opencv-haar-classifier">/g' data/cascade.xml
```

on the saved detector to add the missing classifier type.

Either method should allow you to run

```
opencv_performance -data data -info cars.txt
```

to test your detector.